# Evaluation of this constant expression throws an exception. error in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

this is my code:

```
const InputDecoration kTextFieldDecoration = InputDecoration(
    filled: true,
    fillColor: Colors.white,
    icon: Icon(Icons.location_city, color: Colors.white,),
    hintText: "Enter city name",
    hintStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.grey
    ),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide.none,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
    )
);
```

I am getting the error whenever I add `const`.

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61227026/evaluation-of-this-constant-expression-throws-an-expression) it is given that we have to give compile time constants to declare it as `const`, but in my code I have given compile time constants.

I saw somewhere that if constructor was `const` then I can't use `const` while creating object, what is the reason for this?

The error comes only for `OutlineInputBorder` as it has `const` constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [documentation here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BorderRadius/BorderRadius.circular.html), you will see that `BorderRadius.circular(radius)` internally is the same as `BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(radius))`.

Try to replace this line in you code:

```
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
```

with this:

```
borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))
```

Now it will work with `const`. The explanation is that `BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))` is also a constant, therefore valid inside another constant declaration. But the shorthand version you use can only be evaluated during runtime because of the `this` keyword in `BorderRadius.circular` constructor.

Comment: The important point is that `BorderRadius.circular` is not a `const` constructor and therefore can't be used in a `const` context. (It unfortunately can't be a `const` constructor because it can't invoke the `Radius.circular` unconditionally as a `const` constructor.)